# I am using cnosdb sample function, and I have some questions about tag sampling

Tags: cnosdb

In the process of testing the sample function, I found that for the same sample of the same tag column, the results are different with or without field, as follows:
[image]

[image]

The 'ta' column only has the value 'a', and the 'fa' column has a different value for each

For this problem, with respect to column ta, I am more confused as to which result should be adopted